# UI-GRID Single Input Filtering

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Whats the best way to handle grid filtering with one input.  Is there a simpler way then dealing with it this way:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/321_singleFilter

I also want to filter with every keystroke, not click a button.

Thanks

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/321_singleFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at filtering on multiple columns, thats probably the best way. To make it filter on every key stroke, you can add a "ng-change" to the text input and call the filter function as in the example.

```
 <input ng-model='filterValue' ng-change='filter()'/>
```

if you have a large dataset and you filter on every key stroke, there will be performance lag unless you handle it properly inside the filter function.